# Fake visa stamped in old passport, could this affect my new student visa application to the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, student-visas

I applied for a US visa last year through an agent. The agent stamped an Ethiopian visa in my passport, he said that would increase my chances of obtaining a US visa. How he got the visa stamp I don't know. I didn't go for any capturing or biometric. The Ethiopian visa he stamped was handwritten. The US denied me but they didn't give me a reason.

Now, I am applying for student visa to the UK, I have gotten a new passport to get rid of the visa record but the new passport bears the previous passport number.  My question is one, will the UK go to the extent of checking the record in the previous passport since I am applying for a tier 4 student visa?

Two, I have been advised not to mention that I have applied for visa before. But my fear is, what if that Ethiopian visa actually exists and is valid, if I do not declare that I have applied for visa before and they find out that I have a visa in my previous passport, will this look like I'm trying to cover up something cause a refusal?

Third, if the US actually denied my visa due to a fake visa stamp, and they banned me, how do I find out they banned me and will the ban to the . US also affect my UK plans?

Comment: So, you have applied for a US visa before, who is telling you not to say you have applied for a visa before? And who was it that told you the US denied you, the same agent who gave you a fake visa?

Comment: You must tell the truth. The UK and US (and Australia, Canada, and New Zealand) share immigration data so you should assume the UK will know about any previous applications/denials.

Comment: Stop taking advices from such people. Immigration officials are much "smarter" then you: they see everyday the same attempts, so they have much experience about that. Your passport is tempered (so it cannot be trust), you used fake official documents, so your documents and words are taken (for next few years) as toilet paper. You ruined your chances. Every time you apply you decrease future successful rates. Take it as punishment, for next 5 to 10 years forget long distance travels. We all do errors, and we all pay consequences.

Comment: @Uciebila, I went for the US visa interview, and they denied me. Though I dont know if the Ethiopian visa was fake or legit. My suspicion started months after when i went through the passport and i started wondering. The agent didnt tell me how he got it.

Comment: You can get details of your US Immigration file by making a Freedom of Information Act request https://www.dhs.gov/dhs-foia-privacy-act-request-submission-form

Comment: OT I'd be reporting the agent to the Ethiopian authorities.  Countries tend to take a dim view of people committing fraud like that.

Comment: Your first agent may have _caused_ your visa refusal. Your second agent appears to be trying to cause you to get banned. I agree you should stop taking advice from dodgy agents; more generally it's a bad idea to use agents at all. Nearly every visa application can be prepared yourself without an agent, and then you can ensure that it is done correctly.

Answer (score 5):

If UK immigration discover that you have used a fake visa, then it is very likely that they will deny you entry. It's not out of the question that they will effectively ban you from the UK, although it's unlikely because you didn't try to use the fake visa to get entry to the UK. It's possible that the US already knows about the fake visa, in which case British authorities may find out about it - but probably unlikely or US immigration would have told you.

There is no chance your visa is genuine. Agents cannot grant genuine visas and do not have the authority to put visa stamps in a passport.

By far your best option is to get a new passport, and then make your application without making any mention of the Ethiopian visa. You should definitely tell them about the US visa rejection. If it's already known that you used deception in the US application there is not much you can do about it. If you get a rejection that mentions deception then consult a UK immigration attorney.

Comment: To be clear, however: in any new visa application, if the OP is asked if he has been previously denied a US visa, he should answer affirmatively.

Comment: Remember that the immigration officers have been doing their job mostly for years. They have seen every trick in the book. And they can easily find out that you have been denied a US visa. Having a previous visa denial is a small problem. Lying about it turns it into a HUGE problem.

Answer (score 0):

The UK can effectively deny any future visa applications if they suspect you knew your Ethiopian visa was fake but I don't believe they'll ban you from the UK unless they are more than certain you knew the visa was fake.

Comment: They can very well deny a visa based on suspicion of fraud.